# Ceph: An error occurred (InvalidRange) when calling the CreateBucket operation: Unknown

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket, ceph

I'm trying to use the aws s3api command line tool to create an S3 bucket on my Ceph object store. I've previously used this command successfully, and have other Ceph object stores (VMs from the same image) that I can successfully run the command against.

I've created an empty S3 user on my object store, configured the AWS CLI with keys with `aws configure`, which I am confident are correct as I can run:

```
[root@localhost ] ~> aws s3api --endpoint=https://10.254.2.130:7480 list-buckets --no-verify-ssl
/usr/lib/fence-agents/bundled/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:768: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "s3user",
        "ID": "s3user"
    },
    "Buckets": []
}
```

However trying to create a bucket, I get this error:

```
[root@localhost ] ~> aws s3api --endpoint=https://10.254.2.130:7480 create-bucket --bucket newbucket --no-verify-ssl
/usr/lib/fence-agents/bundled/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:768: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)

An error occurred (InvalidRange) when calling the CreateBucket operation: Unknown
```

I'm struggling to find anywhere with useful information on the error (the AWS documentation barely mentions it). Does anyone have any pointers as to how to debug this further? I've tried the --debug flag without any luck.

I realise the --no-verify-ssl usage isn't great also, we have a solution in the works for that.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to missing Ceph data pools for our S3 buckets.

`ceph osd lspools` prints out the list of pools on the Ceph cluster, from which I identified the problem.